# Scroll Android WebView to next page using java script

Tags: javascript, android

Please anyone help me to scroll my webview with local (single) html file to next page(continuation of the first view) on a button click using `loadUrl()` method. My friend give me this code to make that work. But i dont know how it is done properly.

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height());
```

Also help me to add a flip animation between these scrolled views. I am using a single html file placed on the assets folder. Android version is 4.1.  Any answers will be a great help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i got this one. I am posting this answer because it may help someone.

```
        int HeightWv,contentHts;

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            System.err.println("Find     Height->"+HeightWv);

            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(HeightWv==0){contentHts= 0;}
                    else if(HeightWv!=0){contentHts= HeightWv;}
                    HeightWv = wv.getHeight();
                    Log.e("1",""+ HeightWv);
                    HeightWv = HeightWv+contentHts;
                    Log.e("2",""+ HeightWv);
                    scrolpage();
                     }});
               Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2);
            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(HeightWv==0){contentHts= 0;}
                    else if(HeightWv!=0){contentHts= HeightWv;}
                    HeightWv = wv.getHeight();
                    Log.e("3",""+ HeightWv);
                    HeightWv = contentHts-HeightWv;
                    Log.e("4",""+ HeightWv);
                    scrolpage();
                     }});
         }
        public void scrolpage(){
            wv.scrollTo(0, HeightWv);
            Log.e("scroll",""+ HeightWv);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not that great, since it does not handle the limits of your document's height (you will need to calculate `minHeight` and `maxHeight` and then check every time..). Instead, you could simply use [build-in](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#pageDown(boolean)) one line code: `webView.pageUp(false)` and `webView.pageDown(false);` and that's all!